# Compute $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x^2}f(t)dt$ for continuous $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Question: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then compute $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x^2}f(t)dt$.

My attempt (may be wrong ): let $F$ be the antiderivative of $f$. Then $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x^2}f(t)dt=\frac{d}{dx}(F(x^2)-F(a))$ by FTC. Is it? Does such differentiation have a special name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. Notice it simplifies to $2xf(x^2)$. If you think about it, you can use the chain rule by differentiating with respect to the upper limit $x^2$ first. Explicitly, take $y=x^2$ in $\frac{d}{dy}\int_a^y f(t)dt=f(y)$, then use $\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}$.

Comment: Not sure I get it. Can you demonstrate how to use chain rule by differentiating with respect to the upper limit $x^2$ first?

Comment: @Shara See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it’s called Leibniz-rule, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule.

Comment: can it be computed without preknowledges of partial derivatives?

Comment: In your special case no partial derivative occur.

Comment: WOW, I'm incredibly surprised that this is actually called Leibniz rule, given that there is also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule ! I thought all these years that my lecturers made a mistake by not calling it chain rule.

Comment: @CalvinKhor: as you may have observed the rule is an immediate consequence of chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(x) =\int_a^xf(t)dt$, $h(x) =x^2$, and compute the derivative of $g\circ h$, it is $g'(h(x))h'(x) =f(x^2)(2x)$.